# How to loop through an array to generate js code?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Is there a way to loop through an array (or something similar) when generating js code? For example, I have this in mongoose:

```
    users.updateOne({'_id': req.user._id}
                , {
                ["local.minMinutes"]: req.body.minMinutes

                , ["local.color1U"]: req.body.color1U
                , ["local.color2U"]: req.body.color2U
                , ["local.color3U"]: req.body.color3U
                , ["local.color4U"]: req.body.color4U
                , ["local.color5U"]: req.body.color5U
});
```

I'd like to be able to say "loop through 1 to 5" instead of having to write each individual number out, but a for() loop inside the mongoose call is giving all sorts of error. I hope this question is specific enough - thank you!

Comment: Are you using something like [Lodash](https://lodash.com) which has better `map`-type methods?

Comment: I'm currently using node.js with express if that's any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to create the object by copying the properties from `req.body`.

```
obj = {
};
for (prop in req.body) {
    obj[`local.${prop}`] = req.body[prop];
}
users.updateOne({'_id': req.user._id}, obj);
```